Gazebo gpu lidar seems distorded in Ignition (in comparison to gazebo classic)
I am trying to port a ros1 example (clearpath's husky simulator) into ros2.
For ROS1 Noetic / Gazebo Classic 11.10, the simulated velodyne lidar config is:
<gazebo reference="${name}">
<sensor type="gpu_ray" name="${name}-VLP16">
  <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
  <visualize>false</visualize>
  <update_rate>${hz}</update_rate>
  <ray>
    <scan>
      <horizontal>
        <samples>${samples}</samples>
        <resolution>1</resolution>
        <min_angle>${min_angle}</min_angle>
        <max_angle>${max_angle}</max_angle>
      </horizontal>
      <vertical>
        <samples>${lasers}</samples>
        <resolution>1</resolution>
        <min_angle>-${15.0*M_PI/180.0}</min_angle>
        <max_angle> ${15.0*M_PI/180.0}</max_angle>
      </vertical>
    </scan>
    <range>
      <min>${collision_range}</min>
      <max>${max_range+1}</max>
      <resolution>0.001</resolution>
    </range>
    <noise>
      <type>gaussian</type>
      <mean>0.0</mean>
      <stddev>0.0</stddev>
    </noise>
  </ray>
  <plugin name="gazebo_ros_laser_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_velodyne_gpu_laser.so">
    <topicName>${topic}</topicName>
    <frameName>${name}</frameName>
    <organize_cloud>${organize_cloud}</organize_cloud>
    <min_range>${min_range}</min_range>
    <max_range>${max_range}</max_range>
    <gaussianNoise>${noise}</gaussianNoise>
  </plugin>
</sensor>
</gazebo>

In ROS2-Humble / Gazebo Ignition / Fortress, the simulated velodyne lidar config is:
<gazebo reference="${name}_laser">
<sensor name="${name}" type="gpu_lidar">
<update_rate>${update_rate}</update_rate>
<visualize>true</visualize>
<always_on>true</always_on>
<ignition_frame_id>${name}_laser</ignition_frame_id>
<topic>$(arg namespace)/sensors/${name}/scan</topic>
<lidar>
  <scan>
    <horizontal>
      <samples>${samples_h}</samples>
      <resolution>1</resolution>
      <min_angle>${min_ang_h}</min_angle>
      <max_angle>${max_ang_h}</max_angle>
    </horizontal>
    <vertical>
      <samples>${samples_v}</samples>
      <resolution>1</resolution>
      <min_angle>${min_ang_v}</min_angle>
      <max_angle>${max_ang_v}</max_angle>
    </vertical>
  </scan>
  <range>
    <min>${min_range}</min>
    <max>${max_range}</max>
    <resolution>0.01</resolution>
  </range>
</lidar>
</sensor>
</gazebo>

Here is a comparison the scans. The environment is slightly different, but the ground is perfectly flat in both cases and the robot is not moving. Top view:

Here is the side view on ROS1, we can see that all points on the ground are perfectly (minor the added noise) aligned on same plane:


Here is the side view on ROS2, we can see that points on the ground are not all on the same plane:


You can download those point clouds here:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zpN9heJv3EihLeC4r30bWyWU8S0N_SkY?usp=sharing

Why does the simulated lidar on Gazebo Ignition look so worst than on Gazebo Classic? Am I missing a parameter or is there a better lidar plugin to use?

Maybe try to increase the range: <resolution>0.01</resolution> value. In the gazebo classic file it's set to <resolution>0.001</resolution>
